# Aptana Studio not finding 'assert_equal' Python

Tags: python

Working on "Learn Python the Hard Way" exercise 47 and I have the following project skeleton.

```
ex47 
    bin/
    docs/
    ex47/
        __init__.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        game_tests.py
    game.py
    setup.py
```

Working on Aptana Studio. In game_tests.py I have

```
from nose.tools import *
from game import Room

def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom", 
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")
    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south': south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")
    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
    west.add_paths({'east': start})
    down.add_paths({'up': start})
    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

But Aptana cannot define "assert_equal". I believe `assert_equal` is a built-in function. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert_equal` is in `nose.tools`, however it's not in the `__all__` and not imported with *.
Try
`from nose.tools import assert_equal`

Comment: That worked! However, now Aptana is giving me 'unresolved import' for that though.

Comment: You can probably remove the `from nose.tools import *` line

Comment: I did. I replaced it with `from nose.tools import assert_equal` Still giving me that issue.

Comment: You probably need to re-configure the interpreter somewhere in the settings. So it'll re-scan the package directories. But this is just a guess.